# Hi, Ubuntu is suitable for my laptop, and no problems will arise

Tags: 21.10

Hello fit Ubuntu for my laptop
my laptop HUAWEI MateBook D 14 Nbl-WAQ9R
this is a photo of the bios
and everything will be fine with the drivers and what is inside the components in the laptop[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGE7P.jpg)

and in this photo there are characteristics but not all, but there is a processor, etc.
I'll show you now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcPMR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPE3B.png)
here they are

can be installed on my laptop
HUAWEI Mate Book D 14 Nbl-WAQ9R
Ubuntu and everything is fine and without problems ( LiveCD works well without problems and what else should be checked there so that there are no problems after installation)

and it may happen that my laptop will fail and will not be repaired (brick)

thank you for answering this question
good luck to you

all this is translated into English for
Russian into English

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) Also check https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=076b5dcadd .

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of a language barrier, but I assume this is machine translated and you're meaning to ask Ubuntu would work on this specific laptop.

You can just boot off from the install media and try it without installing. The installer is practically a fully equipped live CD. When you boot off it, just select "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu" when the installer starts.

In general, the computer in your screenshots *should* work, I have a ThinkPad with similar Ryzen. The CPU and GPU both seem to work fine in mine.